# MySQL Datetime <-> Java Date

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, datetime, date

I use Hibernate and I have a datetime in my MySQL database.
Now I want to store the date/time which is a java.util.Date into the database.

So I can write:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
testObject.setCreationDate(df.parse("2010-06-06 13:20:15"));
```

But how can I set the current date/time? Because this is a data field which should store the creation datetime of this object/table row.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Date date = new java.sql.Date();
```

will create the date object with the current date/time.

Comment: They're using `java.util.Date` instead, but it works the same way.